# .net collections optimization

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I'm not really experienced in .Net Collections.

Here I have the code I would like to rewrite somehow.

```
emptyOrganization.Name = "";
var organizations = new List<IOrganization>();
organizations.Add(emptyOrganization);
organizations.AddRange(_organizationRepository.GetAll(LanguageCurrent.Id));
model.Organizations = organizations;
```

Can this be rewritten in fewer lines?

Comment: Why fewer lines? Write readable code (what you do), don't count lines.

Comment: What is your concern with it as it stands?

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong with it as it is.  Each line you have accomplishes a specific goal.  Less lines doesn't always mean better code.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to use a list instantiator.

Comment: @AlexK. I suspect there is a clean LINQ solution for this.

Comment: @AlexHerrmann: LINQ is not cleaner than `List` methods, actually those can be more efficient since LINQ always create a new list as opposed to `List.Add` or `AddRange`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to use a one liner you could use LINQ:

```
model.Organizations = new IOrganization[]{ emptyOrganization }
.Concat(_organizationRepository.GetAll(LanguageCurrent.Id))
.ToList();
```

But why do you want that? Your code is readable and efficient.

Comment: Yes it is. I just prefer a LINQ way. Would like to learn it in more detail.

Answer (score 6):

(I'm assuming that `emptyOrganization` is an `IOrganization` and that `GetAll` returns an `IEnumerable<IOrganization>` or something similar...)

Your code is already efficient, but you might want to try to make it clearer. You could use:

```
model.Organizations = new[] { emptyOrganization }
    .Concat(_organizationRepository.GetAll(LanguageCurrent.Id))
    .ToList();
```

If you regularly find yourself wanting a collection which is one value followed by the values from another collection, you could always write an extension method for that:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Prepend(this IEnumerable<T> source, T value)
{
    yield return value;
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

Then you'd have:

```
model.Organizations = _organizationRepository.GetAll(LanguageCurrent.Id)
   .Prepend(emptyOrganization)
   .ToList();
```

... which is perhaps the most expressive form. (`Prepend` is also part of [MoreLINQ](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/), so you don't actually have to write it yourself...)

Answer (score 0):

Without using Linq, you can save one line by initializing your collection with the empty organisation:

```
var organizations = new List<IOrganization> {emptyOrganization};
organizations.AddRange(_organizationRepository.GetAll(LanguageCurrent.Id));
```